# Moving Controls based on height of tabControl C#

Tags: c#, position, controls, tabcontrol

So, I'm trying to get some buttons below the tabControl that I have in my form. But it's making all the buttons a different .top height even though they are set to the same thing.
  Is there a better way of getting my buttons to stay below the tab control? The tabControl changes height since the items inside it are changing. And anchoring the buttons just makes them go in crazy positions...

```
 private void ReForm()
    {
        //Reset the position of the buttons
        CloseButton.Top = 0;
        insertOne.Top = 0;
        insertMany.Top = 0;
        HelperButton.Top = 0;
        insertInstance.Top = 0;

        //Make an int for the height and width position of the tab windows controls
        int dtop = 0;
        int theight = 0;
        int twidth = 0;
        int xsize = 0;
        int ysize = 0;

        //Try to find the tab controls that are closest to the bottom, or closest to the right
        //When found, get the height and width of these as well
        try
        {
            foreach (Control ctr in blockDefTab.Controls)
            {
                Control control = (Control)ctr;
                //Get the height position
                if (control.Location.Y >= theight)
                {
                    theight = control.Location.Y;
                    ysize = control.Height;
                }
                //Get the width position
                if (control.Location.X >= twidth)
                {
                    twidth = control.Location.X;
                    xsize = control.Width;
                }
            }

            //Set the selected tab height and width
            //tabControl.SelectedTab.Size = new System.Drawing.Size((twidth + xsize+10), (theight+ysize));
            tabControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(twidth+xsize+20,theight+ysize+40);

            //Find the height of the tabControl in the form
            int formCT = 0;
            int formCH = 0;
            foreach (Control formControl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (formControl.Top >= formCT)
                {
                    if (formControl is Button)
                    {
                        //DoNothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        formCT = formControl.Top;
                        formCH = formControl.Height;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Set button location
            CloseButton.Top = formCH+formCT;
            insertOne.Top = formCH + formCT;
            insertMany.Top = formCH + formCT;
            HelperButton.Top = formCH + formCT;
            insertInstance.Top = formCH + formCT;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: If the Buttons' heights are changing then they still are anchored. If they land on different Top positions then there is more code that does that. Why are you using the last foreach if all you want is the Tabcontrol? What is the meaning of the condition at its start? Are there any other controls involved?

Comment: The top positions are the only thing that seems to be changing. Their position.top isn't used anywhere else in the code.

Comment: I used the last foreach because I was thinking that maybe it had to do with the tabControls height changing and it was causing the tops to be different because of that. There are other controls involved inside of each of the tabs in the tabControl. They change based on parameters within those tabs. Which is why the tabControl is changing height, and why I want the buttons to move, so that they are always underneath the tabControl.

Comment: You could stuff all Button into a Panel and only move that Panel..

Comment: Worked perfectly. Sometimes, it's the most simple things that are the most difficult!

Comment: Good. Well, the problem is gone but the puzzle remains. Always hard to know when to move on..